# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy haciendo una especie de todo list en donde me muestra los datos recogidos del textarea en una lista. iba todo bien hasta que pase a la etapa de guardar en local storage los datos pasando estos string a arreglos. el error que me tira es el siguiente:
***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse ()
    at obtenerTweetLocalStorage (app.js:102)
    at HTMLDocument.localStorageListo (app.js:63)***

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
//variables
const listaTweets = document.getElementById('lista-tweets');

//Events listeners

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
 //cuando se envia el formulario
 document.getElementById('formulario').addEventListener('submit', agregarTweet);
 
 //borrar de lista tweet
 listaTweets.addEventListener('click', borrarTweet);

 //contenido cargado
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', localStorageListo);

}



//Funciones

function agregarTweet(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 // leer el valor desde el textarea (escrito) .value accede directo al valor
 const tweet = document.getElementById('tweet').value;

    
    //crear un boton de borrar
    const botonBorrar = document.createElement('a');
    botonBorrar.classList = 'borrar-tweet';
    botonBorrar.innerText = 'X';
    listaTweets.appendChild(botonBorrar);


    //crear elemento (li) y añadirlo a la lista
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = tweet;
    //agregar al dom el li
    listaTweets.appendChild(li);
 
    //agregamos tweet localstorage
    agregarTweetLocalStorage(tweet);
}


//elimina el tweet del DOM
function borrarTweet(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 if(e.target.className === 'borrar-tweet') {
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
  alert('borraste el tweet');
        console.log(e.target.parentElement.innerText);
 }
}


//Mostrar los datos de localstorage en la lista
function localStorageListo() {
 let tweets;

 tweets = obtenerTweetLocalStorage();

 tweets.forEach(function(tweet) {
    //crear un boton de borrar
    const botonBorrar = document.createElement('a');
    botonBorrar.classList = 'borrar-tweet';
    botonBorrar.innerText = 'X';
    listaTweets.appendChild(botonBorrar);


    //crear elemento (li) y añadirlo a la lista
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = tweet;
    //agregar al dom el li
    listaTweets.appendChild(li);
 });
}



//agregar tweets al local storage
function agregarTweetLocalStorage(tweet) {
    let tweets;
    tweets = obtenerTweetLocalStorage();
    //añado el nuevo tweet
    tweets.push(tweet);

    //convertir string a arreglo para el local storage
    localStorage.setItem('tweets', JSON.stringify(tweets) );
}


//comprueba que haya elementos en localstorage, retorna un arreglo
function obtenerTweetLocalStorage() {
 let tweets;
    //revisamos los valoes del local storage bajo una condicion
 if(localStorage.getItem('tweets') === null) {
  tweets = [];
 } else {
  tweets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tweets') );
 }

 return tweets;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="contenido">
        <div class="container">

            <h1>Local Storage</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                    <label for="tweet">Tweet:</label>
                    <form action="#" id="formulario">
                            <label for="tweet"></label>
                            <textarea id="tweet" class="u-full-width"></textarea>
                            <input type="submit" class="button u-full-width button-primary" value="Agregar">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                    <h2>Mis Tweets</h2>
                    <div id="lista-tweets"></div>
                    <!-- aqui van los tweets del text area -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> <!--#contenido-->

    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Haz un `console.log()` y fíjate qué tiene `localStorage.getItem('tweets')`

Comment: @Dibort gracias por el comment, dentro de la consola dices?

Comment: bueno justo antes de tu JSON.parse, para ver el contenido de localStorage.getItem('tweets') en el momento que vas a hacer el parseo

Comment: Solucionado!, debi haber borrado el cache de los navegadores. @Dibort vale!